# Why we are using generic types in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, user-interface, unit-of-work

```
public interface IEntityService < T> : IService where T : class
{
    void Create(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Update(T entity);
    T SelectById(object pk);
}
```

What is **'T'** of here?

Why we have defined class?

Comment: This is what DRY principal is for.

Answer (score 1):

**What is 'T'** = T is a generic type parameter

You can assign any Type value to it.

**Why we have defined class ?**

But on your example it (i.e. **T**) must be a `Class` type.That is the constrain which it has been defined like this `where T : class`.

**What are Generics ?**

> It allows you to delay the specification of the data type of
>   programming elements in a class or a method, until it is actually used
>   in the program. In other words, generics allow you to write a class or
>   method that can work with any data type.

**Some Advantages of using Generics :**

- It helps you to maximize code reuse, type safety, and performance.
- You can create your own generic interfaces, classes, methods, events,
  and delegates.
- You may create generic classes constrained to enable access to
  methods on particular data types.

You can learn more about it using these articles :

[**Generics**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

[**Generics**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)